# how to change sequence of grub entries from CLI

Tags: grub2

I **don't to want use** grub-customizer **GUI** app . I want to change sequence of grub entries from Terminal . I have some manual entries in `/etc/grub.d/40_custom` which are showing at the top. I want them at the bottom . How can I do that ?

Comment: The grub scripts are run in numerical order. 40_custom should be the last run thus putting them at the bottom

Comment: I suggest you try what paul said in a VM first then implement it if all goes well!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it's recommended you should not touch the `grub.cfg` file it's the most practical way of changing the order of display of menu items, if that's what you are asking. First back up the grub.cfg. Open Terminal and `cd /boot/grub/`, then`sudo cp grub.cfg grub2.cfg`

Type`sudo gedit grub.cfg`. Find your boot option blocks, each starting with the line, `menuentry 'boot option name'`, an opening curly bracket at the end of the first line, and your lines of code that follow. Each entry block should end with a closing curly bracket. Cut and paste them after the final menu entry (in my file this is 'System setup'block) Make sure the final line of what you pasted has a closing curly bracket. Save file, restart and GRUB2 should appear with your boot options at the end.